# Python/Django how to set model datetime field with html date field value

Tags: python, django, forms, post, model

I want to assign values form a simple html form(I dont want to use Django model forms or widgets in this case). All of the fields work fine except the datetime one.

Lets say the html form is as simple as this:

```
<form action="{% url 'main:create' %}" method="post" class="row form">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="expense-block" id="expense-block-0" data-block="0">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="id_name">Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required id="id_name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="id_created_at">Date:</label>
                            <input type="datetime-local" name="created_at" class="form-control" required id="id_created_at">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
```

As you can see for the date input i am using `type="datetime-local"` because I want to select both date and time.

The model is simple:

```
class Expenses(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

However when i save model I get error:

```
The Expenses could not be created because the data didn't validate.
```

Now the reason I am getting this error is because the 'create_at' value that i get from the post looks like this:

```
2018-03-09T11:11
```

So the question is, is it possible with Python to format this date to a normal datetime object? If not, what else can I do in my case?

Comment: use created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) and it will store current time

Comment: I dont want the current time. I want to select any date and time i need

Comment: then you can pass string by converting it into date time like this:-`datetime_object = datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2005  1:33PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')`.In that way you can store anydate and anytime

Comment: I get this: time data '2018-01-07T11:11' does not match format '%Y %m %d %I:%M%p'

Comment: you can see this answer for help:-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-to-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date

Answer (score 1):

```
value="{{ obj.date_field|date:'Y-m-d' }}T{{obj.date_field|time:'H:i'}}"
```